# What is causing my animation to fail on plays after the first?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, animation

My goal is to re-implement mat-tab from the Angular Material component library.

Using the `L` and `R` buttons, I'm playing an animation that adjusts the `left` style on a collection of buttons. The issue I'm having is that I can only play each animation once. For example, I can traverse positions `right from 0 to 1`, and then traverse `left from 1 to 0` - but if I try and traverse `right from 0 to 1` a second time, nothing happens. All of the animations are referenceable in an array, and are not being altered after creation - so why is the behavior changing when I reuse them?

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-facezc?file=app/components/test-window/test-window.component.ts)

Comment: Please put a minimal reproducible example direct into your question see [link]https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunally I was not able to come up with a working solution as I haven't used Angulars animations that much yet, but to your issue: animations are using a state to handle transitions and in your provided example each animation is working only once as each enters it's finished state after playing.

What I tried, but it's only partially working, is to reset animations when moving to the other direction. This works for positons 0 => 1 and 1 => 0 but if you move to position 2 you can only get back to position 1 but not 0 - no idea why.

```
public slideLeft(): void {
  console.log(`sliding from ${this.position} to ${this.position - 1}`);
  if (this.position > 0) {
    console.log(`playing left animation at ${this.position}`);
    let animation = this.leftAnimations[this.position];
    animation.play();
    this.position -= 1;

    // in slideRight use leftAnimations
    this.rightAnimations.forEach(a => a.reset());

    /* also tried it like that
    const pos = this.position;
    animation.onDone(() => {
      console.log(`resetting right animation at ${pos}`);
      this.rightAnimations[pos].reset();
    });
    */
}
```

Perhaps a better solution would be to define a state for each of your steps with transitions for each step so you can use a variable to define in which state your animation is. You would need to find a way how to programmatically bind a variable to your animation state which is normaly done by `[@animationName]="variable"`.

Comment: Thanks for giving it a go. I'm still looking into this and will post my findings once I've resolved it.